# How to Delete All Column Attribute in Models?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code

I have a problem on VS Code.

I want to delete just column attribute for 200 files.

How to delete them on one click?

I tried `(.+?)[Column*/]` on Regex Expression.

```
[Column("JOBSTOP")] public DateTime JobStop { get; set; }
[Column("JOBSTOPAVG")] public DateTime JobStopAvg { get; set; }
[Column("JOBSTOPPRJ")] public DateTime JobStopRj { get; set; }
```

I expect the output of `[Column("JOBSTOP")] public DateTime JobStop { get; set; }` to be `public DateTime JobStop { get; set; }`.

There are many files like this.

Comment: Try `\[Column\("[^"]*"\)]\s*`

Comment: thank you so much Wiktor Stribiżew . its worked :)

Answer (score 1):

1. go to the beginning of the line
2. select multiple lines by pressing shift + alt, drag mouse down
   [image]
3. select section by holding ctrl +shift and -> (right arrow)
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
\[Column\("[^"]*"\)]\s*
```

If you do not care to check for double quotes use a shorter expression:

```
\[Column\([^)]*\)]\s*
```

**Details**

- `\[Column\("` - `[Column("` string
- `[^"]*` - 0+ chars other than `"` (`[^)]*` matches 0 or more chars other than `)`)
- `"\)]` - a `")]` substring
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces.

**Demo**

[image]